# index and aggregate to seach for matching values Excel version to R version

Tags: r, excel

I am using excel to currently find a matching value of a string in a larger string for multiple values. I am trying to group-by but report the strings that I have grouped next to the matching value. I have an example with code I've done in excel and works...I would like this to be converted to R but have not found a way to report this without it being numbers.
Excel version looks like this where the string is what I wanted to be grouped according to searchingString. and Library has the grouping values to check.
I would put this function in row 2 of match1 column:

```
=index($A:$A,aggregate(15,7,row($A:$A)/(isnumber(search($c2, $B:$B))),column(A:A)))

String Library   searchingString    match1    match2   match3   match4   match5
abcdef    a1-1             a1        abcdef   abcdhg   asdabc    12abc   abc34
abcdhg    a1-2             b1        ajke
ajke      b1-2             c3        ghi2      fjghi   ghi32
asdabc    a1-1             d4        hi112
12abc     7-a1
abc34     a1-45
ghi2      c3-ab
hi112     d4 
fjghi     c3-ab1
ghi32     c3-dfg5
```

I was wondering how this can be done in R, I would need to create the match column then do some sort of aggregate not sure how to report them as characters separate as these functions don't translate very well to R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try joining the search data to the search strings by making a list column and unnesting it. Then it's easy to use `str_detect` to find the matching strings, and you can `summarise` to collect those strings in one row. This is not an extremely R-like format to output, however (it might be preferable to keep the long format, before `summarise`). Note also that b1 has two matches, not one as shown in your example.

```r
library(tidyverse)
to_search_in <- read_table2(
"String Library
abcdef    a1-1
abcdhg    a1-2
ajke      b1-2
asdabc    a1-1
12abc     7-a1
abc34     a1-45
ghi2      c3-ab
hi112     d4
fjghi     c3-ab1
ghi32     c3-dfg5"
)
to_search_with <- tibble(searchingString = c("a1", "b1", "c3", "d4"))

to_search_with %>%
  mutate(data = list(to_search_in)) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%
  filter(str_detect(Library, searchingString)) %>%
  select(-Library) %>%
  group_by(searchingString) %>%
  summarise(strings = str_c(String, collapse = ", "))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   searchingString strings                             
#>   <chr>           <chr>                               
#> 1 a1              abcdef, abcdhg, asdabc, 12abc, abc34
#> 2 b1              ajke, fjghi                         
#> 3 c3              ghi2, fjghi, ghi32                  
#> 4 d4              hi112
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>